# How does format.html work inside a block next to a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am confused wheather mailto runs first or the block

```
mail(:to => @recipients, :subject => @subject, :cc => @cc, :from => @from, :reply_to => @reply_to, :date => @date, :bcc => @bcc) do |format|
          format.text unless options[:no_text]
          format.html
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since blocks are objects that are given to a method I'd say the answer to your question is that `mail` gets called before the block, in the sense of being executed.

If you take a look at the [source code of the `mail` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9b72c36783516f5ef8f2fac5f6f342a6a48d8d78/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L617) you can see that it has a `block` parameter. This is the actual block object (I think of type `Proc`) that is being created for and passed on for you when you type `do...end`. Further on at line 648 this block object is passed on to the `collect_responses_and_parts_order` method.

So in the meaning of "what is first" I'd have to say it is the block object, since it is passed to the method and needs to be created before the method can be called.